# How can I switch between main and background thread in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'd like to execute some code in a background thread, and have the background code periodically execute code on the main thread. Something like the following:

```
void functionThatMustBeRunOnMainThread(string arg) {
    Debug.Print("On main thread: "+arg);
}

// Run the task asynchronously. On completion, call completionAction in the main thread.
void launchAsyncBackgroundTask( Action<bool> completionAction ) {
    performInArbitraryBackgroundThread(() => {
        // do first long running thing
        sleep(10);

        // notify main thread
        performOnMainThread(() => {
            functionThatMustBeRunOnMainThread("phase 1");
        });

        // do second long running thing
        sleep(10);

        // notify main thread
        performOnMainThread(() => {
            functionThatMustBeRunOnMainThread("phase 2");
        });

        // do final long running thing
        sleep(10);

        performOnMainThread(() => {
            Debug.Print("Done!");
            completionAction(true);
        });
    });
}
```

I know about `BackgroundWorker` but it doesn't offer the flexibility I'm looking for.

There's two points here -

1. I'm 'calling back' to the main thread multiple times - twice during execution, then a third time to execute the user-supplied completion callback.
2. The code is very readable. Even though two threads are involved, synchronization is implicit or handled elsewhere - reading top to bottom the sequence of events is clear, if only from an idealized perspective. There are no static functions or extra classes to override - it's all happening inline with lambda expressions/closures.

This is trivial to do in Obj-C using Grand Central Dispatch (it pretty much works as above). Is there a C# equivalent?

Comment: Use `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: I wouldn't consider such code trivial or readable, compared to the code you can write using the TPL.

Comment: Moreover, it introduces an extremely tight coupling between the two threads, as the background thread's code requires an intimate knowledge of the code that runs on the main (UI) thread. It's better to have the main thread define the actions it allows and provide abstractions to the background threads to call. That's what the Progress<T> class does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you need quite easily using [`async-await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) along with the [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

This example assumes that your `MethodThatDoesStuffInBackground` or any of the other time-consuming methods are CPU bound operations. If not and they're doing IO, you can drop the use of `Task.Run`:

(This method should be called from the UI thread in order to work properly)

```
public async Task DoStuff()
{
    await Task.Run(() => MethodThatDoesStuffInBackground());

    FunctionThatMustRunOnMainThread();

    await Task.Run(() => MethodThatDoesMoreStuffInBackground());

    FunctionThatMustRunOnMainThread();

    await Task.Run(() => EvenMoreWorkInBackgroundThread());

    FunctionThatMustRunOnMainThread();
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to call this `DoStuff` method from UI thread.

Comment: Add `Task.Delay` for asynchronous delays that *don't* block any threads, maybe `Progress<T>` for signalling between threads using complex event objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im not quite sure the OP needs any `Task.Delay`. He simulated `sleep(10)` for the long running methods.

Comment: Just saying, how much more powerful and cleaner it is to do such a thing in .NET.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Definitely! :)

Comment: And we haven't even started on the multiple concurrency paradigms we have with PLINQ, Dataflow, Reactive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why we love C# :)

Comment: This is actually inverted from what I had above - rather than having one big background function that manages its own the sequence of events, this completely blocks the main thread and has broken the background task up into 3 separate functions. :(

Comment: Why do you assume this blocks the main thread? This does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Oh, I see. What I didn't get is that `await` and `async` are magic keywords that told the UI thread to behave differently (sort of a cooperative multithreading model). Is there any way of initiating this kind of behaviour from a non-UI thread?

Comment: *Is there any way of initiating this kind of behaviour from a non-UI thread?* Do you mean that you want to execute code from a background thread which will be invoked on the UI thread?

Comment: No, I meant something else, but what I meant didn't make sense :) Thanks, your original answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `Task.Run` for background work, `IProgress<T>` for progress updates, and `Task` for completion notification. This approach enables you to keep your background logic in one place, separate from the UI.

Something like this:

```
// Run the task asynchronously. On completion, call completionAction in the main thread.
async Task launchBackgroundTaskAsync( Action<bool> completionAction ) {
  var progress = new Progress<string>(arg => {
      Debug.Print("On main thread: "+arg);
  };

  await Task.Run(() => BackgroundLogic(progress));
  completionAction(true);
}

void BackgroundLogic(IProgress<string> progress) {
  // do first long running thing
  sleep(10);

  // notify main thread
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report("phase 1");

  // do second long running thing
  sleep(10);

  // notify main thread
  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report("phase 2");

  // do final long running thing
  sleep(10);

  if (progress != null)
    progress.Report("Done!");
}
```

Note that the `completionAction` is no longer necessary, since `launchBackgroundTaskAsync` itself returns a `Task`. It can simply be removed without any loss of capability - just have the *callers* of this method use `await`:

```
async Task launchBackgroundTaskAsync() {
  var progress = new Progress<string>(arg => {
      Debug.Print("On main thread: "+arg);
  };

  await Task.Run(() => BackgroundLogic(progress));
}
```

Comment: So I can just throw any arbitrary code into `Progress`? ie, I should consider `Progress` as a synonym for `performOnMainThread`? Is it called synchronously from the perspective of the BG thread (ie the background thread is blocked until `progress.Repert()` returns), or async (background thread operation continues while `progress.Report()` executes async on the main thread)?

Comment: `Progress<T>` takes an `Action<T>` delegate, so you can put any kind of code in it. It operates *asynchronously*, so `progress.Report` won't block the background thread.

Comment: @damian - after some printf() debugging, `performOnMainThread` seems to be close, except at a guess I'd name it `performOnOriginalThread` or whatever.  `Progress<>` must be doing something under the covers, since if you try the same thing with just a plain old `Action<>` it executes on the background thread.  Re your other questions, it looks like `progress.Report()` returns immediately and is not blocked by whatever the main thread does with it.